# Azure Nested Hyper-V Child VM No Internet Access

Tags: azure, hyper-v

I'm having problems getting the internet access working on a child vm inside hyper-v on my azure vm.

I've created two NIC's on azure and assigned them both to the VM.

From there I setup static IP's for both NIC's and create 3 public IP's assigned to NIC#2 (Reserved for VM traffic)

Install Hyper-V, create my first child VM & external switch. Assign that VM onto newly created switch, linked to NIC#2 so IP configurations get passed onto virtual adapter from (Azure virtual adapter NIC2)

Disabled IPV6 to remove any possible conflicts.

Started Child VM and setup NIC to my static address, existing within Azure's configuration for my network.

Still no internet, anyone run into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the step-by-step guide on how to enable nested virtualization in Azure Virtual Machines. Double check your configuration with the guide. Hope it helps.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization